# The IN operator in sql

Tags: sql

In the nobel quiz, there is a question "Write the code which would show the year when neither a Physics or Chemistry award was given'.
My code is as following:

```
    SELECT yr FROM nobel 
  WHERE subject NOT IN ('Chemistry','Physics')
```

The correct code should be:

```
    SELECT yr FROM nobel 
  WHERE yr NOT IN (SELECT yr FROM nobel WHERE subject IN ('Physics', 'Chemistry'))
```

I am wondering why my code is incorrect. Why do we have to use the subquery for this question?
Thanks everyone!

Comment: post your schema so we can see

Comment: Where did the "correct" code come from?

Comment: 1) Pick a database. Tag either MySQL or Postgres. 2)  In any given year there where prizes awarded for something so the first query will return something.

Comment: What if there are multiple awards to more than one subject in same year? So that's why second query.

Comment: What happend when you tested this yourself? You have the data or should have created an example yourself to answer the question and validate your query.

Comment: yeah I tried and It shows me my syntax is error.

Comment: `select yr, array_agg(subject)  @> array['Chemistry', 'Physics']::varchar[] from nobel group by yr having array_agg(subject)  @> array['Chemistry', 'Physics']::varchar[] = 't';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering why my code is incorrect.

The requirement is you must show years "when neither a Physics or Chemistry award was given". They key understanding is asking for *years* with neither a Physics or Chemistry award is not the same as asking for *rows* with neither a Physics or Chemistry award.

Say you have this data:

| yr | subject |
| --- | --- |
| 2023 | Chemistry |
| 2023 | Biology |

With this data, a Chemistry award was given in 2023, which means you must eliminate **ALL** rows for the year 2023, including the Biology row. Your code did not do this, and would incorrectly show the year 2023.

Personally, I'd write this with either [aggregation](https://dbfiddle.uk/XI1R2Gxh), [`NOT EXITS()`](https://dbfiddle.uk/rfwuO36Y), or an [exclusion join](https://dbfiddle.uk/a2ACNPdL), rather than a `NOT IN()`, but the `NOT IN()` subquery in the question can work.

Here is the aggregation solution:

```
select yr
from nobel
group by yr
having sum(case when subject in ('Chemistry', 'Physics') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you! but the question is to show the year when neither a Physics or Chemistry award was given. so no row for Chemistry is what I want.

Comment: @JadeYoung Yes, but with that sample data, an award was given for chemistry in 2023. Based on that criteria, you have to ALSO disqualify the biology row for that year, which your code did NOT do.

Comment: Can you explain more? In my code, I don't filer year. What I filter is just the subject. How come the Biology row will be filter out in your sample data?

Comment: @JadeYoung I updated the explanation in the answer.

Comment: I misunderstood the question! Thanks a lot for your help! really appreciate it :)

Comment: I have one more question in terms of your answer. You mentioned you'd write NOT EXISTS() rather than NOT IN (). Can I ask what's the difference between the two? Thanks!

Comment: @JadeYoung Primarily performance (EXISTS is generally faster), and that not exists doesn't compare with anything anything. It's just true/false based on whether the subquery has a row or not. Click the link on the text to see it work.

Comment: @JadeYoung Thinking more, I'd actually go for a GROUP BY/HAVING solution (now included in the answer).

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot!! You helped me!

Answer (score -1):

Your original query checks for years where the subject is not Chemistry or Physics, which means it could include years where only one of them (either Chemistry or Physics) was not awarded, but the other one was. It doesn't ensure that neither Physics nor Chemistry was awarded in that year.